# C# non-blocking io (ex: reactor pattern)

Tags: c#, node.js, asynchronous

I want to build new server for my new product. It will be http driven and must process alot of requests. For the most part server will query database and process results (the processing itself is negligible comparing to database). I also have somewhat constrained resources for now.

I used to build such things with nodejs but i get tired of dynamic typing. I want something with static typing and some break from javascript. For the first part i think of TypeScript. For the second C#.

Can i build server on C# that is nearly as performant as Node.JS? I don't need multithreaded logic, i want async event driven io.

Are there libraries that can help?
Are there any opensource projects that employ async io that i can look at?

Comment: Async IO is easier and uses less CPU in C#. You'll be fine.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft has posted several examples of using asynchronous operations rather than multi threaded logic on the MSDN.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te.aspx deals with asynchronous sockets
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kztecsys.aspx deals with asynchronous file i/o

You may also want to look into the async methods of the TcpClient object, such as here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.beginaccepttcpclient.aspx

There's a lot of documentation on the msdn for these kinds of operations, I'd advise checking those first and then posting back if you have a specific problem with implementing one of those

Comment: I'd consider the first example you posted to be out-dated. Such code can be massively simplified by using async/await.

Comment: Can you provide more details on async/wait implemetation?

Comment: @RawCode It will have to wait but if nobody else provides one I will try to post an example. In the mean time, look at the MSDN articles, most features of classes like the TcpClient class are explained with code samples at the bottom of the page

Comment: I tried code example from http://www.salmanq.com/blog/net-and-node-js-performance-comparison/2013/03/ and got this -  gist.github.com/miv/6651081

Answer (score 1):

I recommend reading this blog http://www.salmanq.com/blog/net-and-node-js-performance-comparison/2013/03/
It also provides you with some basic code examples to get started.
If you want even more .Net comfort, simply write some MVC web api. There are tons of examples and documentation available

Comment: I tried examples from this post and got following: https://gist.github.com/miv/6651081. C# died in the middle of the test. Now i think it mostly becase of some error in code. But still.